# REQ socket drop message silently if two message coming together very fast

Tags: c++, zeromq

This is a reproducible message silently dropped issue with a very small changes to the lbbroker.cpp.

https://github.com/booksbyus/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/lbbroker.cpp

In the lbbroker.cpp file, a worker will be pop out from work_queue when handling a request from client thread. If we modify the line 163 from `std::string worker_addr = worker_queue.front();` to `static std::string worker_addr = worker_queue.front();`, as the following picture shows. All request will be forwarded to one worker, then we can see some messages will be dropped by the REQ socket the worker. Is it normal? REQ socket cannot receive other message when the worker logic is running ?

The client thread:

```
static void * client_thread(void *arg) {
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t client(context, ZMQ_REQ);

    #if (defined (WIN32))
        s_set_id(client, (intptr_t)arg);
        client.connect("tcp://localhost:5672"); // frontend
    #else
        s_set_id(client); // Set a printable identity
        client.connect("ipc://frontend.ipc");
    #endif

    //  Send request, get reply
    s_send(client, "HELLO");
    std::string reply = s_recv(client);
    std::cout << "Client: " << reply << std::endl;
    return (NULL);
}
```

The worker thread:

```
    //  Worker using REQ socket to do LRU routing
//
static void *
worker_thread(void *arg) {
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t worker(context, ZMQ_REQ);

#if (defined (WIN32))
    s_set_id(worker, (intptr_t)arg);
    worker.connect("tcp://localhost:5673"); // backend
#else
    s_set_id(worker);
    worker.connect("ipc://backend.ipc");
#endif

    //  Tell backend we're ready for work
    s_send(worker, "READY");

    while (1) {
        //  Read and save all frames until we get an empty frame
        //  In this example there is only 1 but it could be more
        std::string address = s_recv(worker);
        {
            std::string empty = s_recv(worker);
            assert(empty.size() == 0);
        }

        //  Get request, send reply
        std::string request = s_recv(worker);
        std::cout << "Worker: " << request << std::endl;

        s_sendmore(worker, address);
        s_sendmore(worker, "");
        s_send(worker, "OK");
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

The main function(start client and worker threads):
Note: `std::string worker_addr = worker_queue.front();` is changed to `static std::string worker_addr = worker_queue.front();` to let all requests from different clients send to one work thread, then some message will be dropped by the REQ socket in work thread.

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    //  Prepare our context and sockets
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t frontend(context, ZMQ_ROUTER);
    zmq::socket_t backend(context, ZMQ_ROUTER);

#if (defined (WIN32))
    frontend.bind("tcp://*:5672"); // frontend
    backend.bind("tcp://*:5673"); // backend
#else
    frontend.bind("ipc://frontend.ipc");
    backend.bind("ipc://backend.ipc");
#endif

    int client_nbr;
    for (client_nbr = 0; client_nbr < 10; client_nbr++) {
        pthread_t client;
        pthread_create(&client, NULL, client_thread, (void *)(intptr_t)client_nbr);
    }
    int worker_nbr;
    for (worker_nbr = 0; worker_nbr < 3; worker_nbr++) {
        pthread_t worker;
        pthread_create(&worker, NULL, worker_thread, (void *)(intptr_t)worker_nbr);
    }
    //  Logic of LRU loop
    //  - Poll backend always, frontend only if 1+ worker ready
    //  - If worker replies, queue worker as ready and forward reply
    //    to client if necessary
    //  - If client requests, pop next worker and send request to it
    //
    //  A very simple queue structure with known max size
    std::queue<std::string> worker_queue;

    while (1) {

        //  Initialize poll set
        zmq::pollitem_t items[] = {
                //  Always poll for worker activity on backend
                { backend, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
                //  Poll front-end only if we have available workers
                { frontend, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 }
        };
        if (worker_queue.size())
            zmq::poll(&items[0], 2, -1);
        else
            zmq::poll(&items[0], 1, -1);

        //  Handle worker activity on backend
        if (items[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {

            //  Queue worker address for LRU routing
            worker_queue.push(s_recv(backend));

            {
                //  Second frame is empty
                std::string empty = s_recv(backend);
                assert(empty.size() == 0);
            }

            //  Third frame is READY or else a client reply address
            std::string client_addr = s_recv(backend);

            //  If client reply, send rest back to frontend
            if (client_addr.compare("READY") != 0) {

                    {
                        std::string empty = s_recv(backend);
                        assert(empty.size() == 0);
                    }

                std::string reply = s_recv(backend);
                s_sendmore(frontend, client_addr);
                s_sendmore(frontend, "");
                s_send(frontend, reply);

                if (--client_nbr == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (items[1].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {

            //  Now get next client request, route to LRU worker
            //  Client request is [address][empty][request]
            std::string client_addr = s_recv(frontend);

            {
                std::string empty = s_recv(frontend);
                assert(empty.size() == 0);
            }

            std::string request = s_recv(frontend);

            static std::string worker_addr = worker_queue.front();
            worker_queue.pop();

            s_sendmore(backend, worker_addr);
            s_sendmore(backend, "");
            s_sendmore(backend, client_addr);
            s_sendmore(backend, "");
            s_send(backend, request);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and put that inline into your question, not into a link to some external, volatile site. For output, include that inline as well as text, not as a picture. Also, it seems you suspect this to be a bug. In that case, report a bug ticket, though it's probably valid to verify that here. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Thanks, I modified this question as you suggested.